# Ejecutar query cada X tiempo

Tags: php, ajax

Intento refrescar cada cierto tiempo el valor de una BBDD.
Tengo el siguiente fichero:

**db.php**

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "DEMO");

$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);     
if (!$result)     
  die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error()); 

  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    
    if ($rows) {    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
      echo $row['id'];          
    } 
} 
mysqli_close($mysqli);  
?>
```

El resultado de esta query, me da un numero.

En un segundo fichero, llamado **demo.php** tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'db.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

Cuando ejecuto demo.php, no me muestra nada. Se queda la página en blanco.
Que me está fallando?

En la consola, aparece el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at refresh_div (demo.php:8)
refresh_div @ demo.php:8
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ demo.php:17
18:40:23.652
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has mirado en la consola del navegador? de momento veo una errata (la etiqueta `<div>` sin el `< ` inicial

Comment: ha sido un copiar y pegar. Pero en la web estaria con el "<"

Comment: veo esto: ncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at refresh_div (demo.php:7)
refresh_div @ demo.php:7
18:35:03.547

Answer (score 0):

He añadido finalmente la siguiente linea:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```